# Integrating TeamCity Build Results in JIRA

Tags: teamcity, jira

I want to integrate the result of my build as a comment in my JIRA tickets. Is there a way this can be achieved. This seemed promising: https://github.com/mamirov/jirareporter/wiki/TeamCity-JIRA-Reporter-(ENG)

However, I can't seem to get it to work. My build agent doesn't seem to run this step (the last step - JIRA Reporter)

Is there any way or any tools I can make use of to achieve my objective of integrating my build results from TeamCity into a JIRA ticket as a comment?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [REST API to create the comment](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-add-comment).

Comment: Sorry I don't follow. How can I automate this from TeamCity so on a build it sends the comment to a JIRA ticket?

Answer (score 1):

There is a [dedicated Jira plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.stiltsoft.jira.teamcity/cloud/overview) for TeamCity integration. It is not free but might be well worth the price.

As to JIRA Reporter:
For the build step to execute even for a failed build make sure to set step's "[Execution policy](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/Configuring+Build+Steps#ConfiguringBuildSteps-Executionpolicy)" in the advanced settings of the step to "Even if some of previous steps failed".

Comment: I've set that as the option for the execution policy. However it still says no compatible build agents when running the build steps. Are you currently using JIRA Reporter?